# C-strings, how to determine if the characters are between 6 and 10 long?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, char, c-strings

I am beginner programmer. I am writing a program to check if the password, as a c-string, is between 6 and 10 characters long. If not, the user has to re-enter the password until it meets the requirement. For the input validation part of the program, it works when the password is less than 6 characters -- telling the user to re-enter the password. But, when it is more than 10 characters long, it doesn't display an error that it is more than 10 characters long. How would I fix this? Thanks for your input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int SIZE = 12; // Maximum size for the c-string
char pass[SIZE];   // to hold password c-string.
int length;


// get line of input
cout << "Enter a password between 6 and " << (SIZE - 2) << "characters long:\n";
cin.getline(pass, SIZE);


length = strlen(pass);

while (length < 6 || length > 10)
{
cout << "Error: password is not between 6 and " << (SIZE - 2) << " characters long.\n"
     << "Enter the password again: ";
cin.getline(pass, SIZE);
    length = strlen(pass);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best solution here: Just stop using C-style string handling and switch to the much nicer facilities around `std::string`.

Comment: You will be accessing beyond the `password` array bound if the user enters more than 10 characters since it can only accommodate for 11 including the null terminator added by `getline`, so better to use `std::string` as suggested by Baum mit Augen.

Comment: If you're going to check if the input is more than 10 characters long, you first have to write code that's capable of accepting an input that's more than 10 characters long so that you have something to check. You haven't done that.

Comment: I suspect you are learning from an older book or tutorial (probably book). There are a wealth of resources out there to learn C++ in a safer, easier, and more modern pattern using the standard library or alternatives. I strongly recommend seeking a good, *new* introduction to C++.

Comment: Thanks for your input and expertise all, the error had to do with the char array size as the comments mentioned. I updated the program, and now it works fine. I know using std::string is easier, but the program is required to use cstrings for learning purposes.

Comment: @Lightypulse: You need to specify in your question if you have any requirements, so that people don't waste time provided irrelevant answers.

Comment: @dreamlax Yea sorry about that all, I will be carefully more specified next time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're using cstrings, since normal strings work just as well. Here is how I would rewrite it:

```
string pass;
cout << "Enter password: ";
cin  >> pass;
while (pass.length() > 10 || pass.length() < 6)
{
  cout << "Not the right length, try again: ";
  cin  >> pass;
}
```

If you need to have the password in an array, use this:

```
//To use the c_string version of it, type 
pass.c_str();
return 0;
```

This is untested however, but it should work.

Comment: `char password[pass.length()];` is not valid C++. Array sizes must be compile-time constants.

Comment: That's the part I was worried about. How would you implement it?

Comment: `std::string::c_str()` also return a c string.

Comment: The password string inside `pass` is already in a `char` array. Just call `pass.c_str()` to get a pointer to that array.

Comment: It would be good to test `cin` or even `cin >> pass` as part of the loop condition, so that you don't get an infinite loop if reading fails

Comment: True, in most of my programs, I include: `cin.clear();` and `cin.sync();` to make sure it stops the reading.

Answer (score 1):

Your not allowing a password over 10 characters. C strings are null terminated so 10 chars plus null byte is 11. You will only ever get a 10 length. P.s. I would suggest

```
    char password[SIZE+2]
```

Makes it clearer that the constant is the maximum length of the password

EDIT

I agree with the other posts that std::string is a better option but it's also important especially for a biginer to understand problems not just accept solutions because that's what should be done

Answer (score 0):

```
const int SIZE = 11;
char password[SIZE];
```

There is no way the `password` can store more than 11 chars (where the last char is NULL terminator `'\0'`).

`cin.getline(password, SIZE);`

There is no way you will get more than you asked, which is `SIZE`.

A quick fix would be changing it to
`char password[SIZE + 1];`. Why? Because it will be capable to store more chars than your wanted, thus allowing you to check if input is too long.

Of course, you have to change your `cin.getline(...` to `cin.getline(password, SIZE + 1);` as well.

You forgot to update your `length` in that `if` too. I would suggest do something like this instead, making it cleaner:

```
const int SIZE = 11;
char password[SIZE + 1];

while (true) // Create a loop
{
    cout << "Enter a password between 6 and "
         << (SIZE - 1) << " characters long:\n";

    // If bad input, discard the remaining input
    if (!cin.getline(password, SIZE + 1))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    }

    int length = strlen(password);

    // Check input validation if password is bet. 6 and 10 characters
    if (length < 6 || length > 10)
    {
        cout << "Password is not between 6 " << (SIZE - 1)
             << " characters.\n Please enter your password again:\n";
    }
    else { break; } // Break loop if input vaild
}
```

Comment: BTW, it is better to use std::string in C++.

Comment: If the user enters more than 10 chars, the next read after "Please enter your password again" will read the next characters from the same line, whereas OP probably wants to discard that and prompt for input